# Using assigns() in rspec view specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to model one of my view specs after the examples given [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec).

From my Gemfile: `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'`

```
# /app/spec/views/teams/index.html.haml_spec.rb
RSpec.describe "teams/index", type: :view do

  before (:each) do
    assigns(:teams, [
      FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team 1"),
      FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team 2")
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of teams" do
    render

    expect(rendered).to match /Team 1/
    expect(rendered).to match /Team 2/
  end
end
```

This spec fails with:

```
 1) teams/index renders a list of teams
     Failure/Error: assigns(:teams, [
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

I don't understand the failure... I'm doing exactly what the docs tell me to do. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **assign** instead **assigns** :

```
before (:each) do
  assign(:teams, [
    FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team 1"),
    FactoryGirl.create(:team, name: "Team 2")
  ])
end
```